# Unity Shader - Moving one texture around and on top of another texture

Tags: unity, shaders, graphics, graphics-programming

I have a shader that applies a texture to a sphere with lighting, making it look like a nicely lit planet:

[image]

The code for my shader is here:

```
Shader "Custom/CloudedSurface"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Clouds ("Clouds", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Pass {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardBase" }
            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"
 
                struct appdata
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    float3 normal : NORMAL;
                };
                struct v2f
                {
                    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    float3 normal : NORMAL;
                    float3 worldPos : TEXCOORD1;
                };
                sampler2D _MainTex;
                sampler2D _Clouds;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;
                float4 _Clouds_ST;
                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                    o.normal = normalize(mul(v.normal, unity_WorldToObject).xyz);
                    return o;
                }
                fixed4 _LightColor0;
                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    float dif = max(0.05, dot(i.normal, normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz)));
                    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                    fixed4 result = fixed4(col.rgb * dif * _LightColor0.rgb, 1);
                    return result;
                }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

It is quite simple as it just applies a texture to a sphere with some basic lighting. It needs to run on a mobile so I want to keep it simple for high performance. No need for complex effects or details etc.

The issue is that I need to apply a second texture (called "Clouds" above) and move this around the sphere, whilst keeping it under the influence of lighting. This will make it look like clouds are moving around the planet. Please can someone help me to do this?

I don't think it should be hard, but whenever I try it combines the two textures together and moves them simultaneously. I don't know how to move the clouds independently and "on top" of the main texture to create the illusion. Maybe I need a second pass? I have tried to no luck.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: "but whenever I try it combines the two textures together and moves them simultaneously" — can you show us what you tried that caused this error? It's easier to fix errors when we can see them.

Answer (score 0):

The code that works is:

````
Shader "Custom/CloudedSurface"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Clouds ("Clouds", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
 
    SubShader
    {
        Pass {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardBase" }
 
            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata 
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    float3 normal : NORMAL;
                };
 
                struct v2f 
                {
                    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    float3 normal : NORMAL;
                    float2 cloudUV : TEXCOORD2;
                };
 
                sampler2D _MainTex;
                sampler2D _Clouds;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;
                float4 _Clouds_ST;
 
                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                    o.normal = normalize(mul(v.normal, unity_WorldToObject).xyz);
                    o.cloudUV = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _Clouds);
                    return o;
                }
 
                fixed4 _LightColor0;
 
                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target 
                {
                    float dif = max(0.05, dot(i.normal, normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz))); 

                    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                    fixed4 clouds = tex2D(_Clouds, i.cloudUV);
                    col = lerp(col, clouds, clouds.a);

                    fixed4 result = fixed4(col.rgb * dif * _LightColor0.rgb, 1); 
                    return result;
                }
            ENDCG
        }
        
    }
}
```
````

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained what you changed and why that helped.